# how to display data from function in another component in angular2?

Tags: angularjs, function, angular

I've got a component `dataservice.ts` with a function() that will provide a string by:

```
    httpString: string = "https://";
    complUrl: string = "";
    something: string = "something";
    something: string = ".something";

    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }

    buildUrl(): void {
        let pId = "015111810666";
        let dId = "i21wcwg2hssv2t9";         

        this.complUrl = this.httpString + this.something + this.something + pId + dId;
        console.log(complUrl);
    }
```

and i want to query `complUrl` in another component - `myComponent.ts` - by OnInit

```
constructor(private myDataService: MyDataService) {
}  
ngOnInit() { 
 this.myDataService.buildUrl();  
}
```

what am i doing wrong? i guess it's simple, but i can't figure it out.

Comment: you missed a `"` here `something: string = "something;` and do you have the function in another component or provider?

Comment: thanks! mhm. yes as i said: i've got a component dataservice.ts and a component where i want to run the function buildUrl()

Comment: are you using the dataservice component in the the other component html?

Comment: `error_handler.js:45 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: complUrl is not defined
ReferenceError: complUrl is not defined`

Comment: no. i'm not using the function in the html. i'm using it in the .ts via `ngOnInit() { 
 this.myDataService.buildUrl();  
}`

Comment: can you add app.module.ts in the question?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `this` in your console.log, which causes your error message: `complUrl is not defined`, so it should be:

```
console.log(this.complUrl);
```

And just as a comment, you have replaced "real" variables with `something`, right? Otherwise you have two identical variables.

Comment: @edamerau, did this answer help you? If so, could you kindly accept this answer? :)